# How to automate azure media player using selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, video-streaming, azure-media-player

We are going to include azure media player to provide some video content in our project. as part of testing, we need to automate the controls and verify text, image or frames if necessary. currently we are using selenium. Can we automate directly using selenium with javascriptexecutor or do we need any other plug-ins to do that?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All controls of azure media player can be automated using selenium. From the sample media player that I have gone through I could figure out that Play, pause and full screen buttons could be easily done using selenium element click method. while the video quality toggle and the volume can be automated easily using the actions class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but along with basic controls of the player, is there a possibility to verify text or image in the frame at particular time of video something like that.